# OTS (Open Text Summarizer)

Tags: linux

I was trying to install OTS (Open Text Summarizer) on ubuntu 12.10.

I downloaded the package `ots-0.5.0` and  ran `./configure` and finally got this error:

> configure: error: Library requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.0 libxml-2.0 >=
>   2.4.23) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config
>   can find them.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it basically tells you pretty clearly: you need these two libraries. Run the following command to check if you have those libraries installed:

```
ldconfig -p | egrep '(libxml|libglib)'
```

If they don't show up, install them:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libglib2.0-dev
```

Comment: libxml2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-nu/libxml2.so.2
libxml2.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1
libglibmm-2.4.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 libglib-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib- But s2.0.so.0  libglib-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
 libglib-2.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so But,still can't work properly with ./confugur

Answer (score 0):

It says that module version less than required

pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0

pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0

There may be many reasons for that - pkg-config not installed, glib-2.0-devel or libxml-2.0-devel not installed. Or these *-devel packages did not put *.pc files into /usr/lib/pkgconfig.

You can install all those packages from main repo.
If module versions will be lower than reqired, try to find/google appropriate versions of this packages in PPA.